# Geometric Progressions ratio

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't really know how to find the ratio of 3/2, any ideas? thanks!

[image: Picture]

Comment: The ratio for a geometric progression is nothing but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ which is equal to 3/2.

Comment: Just divide two consecutive terms ($n^{th}$ by $(n-1)^{th}$) to see what the ratio is: $$\frac{3^3\cdot 2^{16}}{3^2\cdot2^{17}} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: It would *really* help if you would put this in context, explain what the text is attempting to demonstrate, and just what the question is.  The ratio of *what* exact.  The ratio of $\frac 32$ is just $\frac 32$ and the ratio $\frac {14}{27}$ is $\frac {14}{27}$.  So asking what the ratio doesn't mean anything.  In this case you are asked for the ratio *between consecutive terms of a geometric series* so it'd be useful if you *said* that.  In which case you just divide two terms: $\frac {3^32^{16}}{3^22^{17}} = \frac 32$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply notice that each successive term is tripled the previous ($\times 3$) and then halved ($\times 1/2$). It's more a pattern-recognition thing than anything formal.

Of course, if you want, you can manually divide any $n^{th}$ term by the preceding term to also see the ratio in a geometric series. That would be the more proper way to demonstrate that the ratio of the series is $3/2$.

Comment: Thank you guys! I got it!